# How to modify ActiveRecord save callback to write to multiple Postgres schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two different schemas containing the same table in PostgreSQL. I'd like to write the changes made in my Rails application to both these tables existing in two schemas.

I have been trying to work my way using the save callback in ActiveRecord to write to both the schemas but have been unsuccessful.

Is there a way to do the above or at least capture the SQL generated in the save callback and execute the SQL query against a different schema?

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful. But if you just need two same tables in different schema,  you should consider [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html).

Comment: You can manually switch connections with 
`ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to`. However if you use a a callback you can't just call `.save` again as it would lead to infinite recursion. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#using-manual-connection-switching

Comment: You could create an upsert trigger in raw sql. But would need a guard for stopping the trigger at a certain point to avoid infinite recursion. There' s a lot of debate about pg_trigger_depth to stop the recursion, but I used it and it worked well in my situation